# AngularJS error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I'm trying to make my first controller and getting this error:

*Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined*

I've simplified my code to find the error but no luck. It looks to my like I'm creating the controller and the books array in the script and referencing the controller letter by letter in the div. What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-controller="TestController">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="b in books">{{ b.title + ' by ' + b.author }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        function TestController() {
            this.books = [{title: 'Angela', author: 'Donald Duck'}, {title: 'Angles', author: 'Dirty Harry'}];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm following a tutorial and as JB Nizet points out my knowledge is "out of date". I found that it stopped working after the first half of the 1.3.0-betas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a very long time since global functions aren't controllers anymore in angular.js. You need to register the function as a controller in your module:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

and in the JS code:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.books = ...;
});
```

Your angular knowledge is out-of-date. re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

or the more simplified way

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController($scope) {
$scope.books= [{title: 'Angela', author: 'Donald Duck'}, {title: 'Angles', author: 'Dirty Harry'}];

}
```