# Argument 'testController' is not a : Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visualforce

I'm working on Salesforce Visualforce template and components, I have the below code embedded and I'm trying to fix the bug.

I did check the similar link here : [AngularJS error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205895/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-testcontroller-is-not-a-function-got-unde)

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ng-app="vsTestApp">
...
    <c:TestController />
    <c:TestTemplate />
...
</div>
```

The code for `TestController`

```
<apex:component >
<script>
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('vsTestApp', []);
}());

(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('vsTestApp')
    .controller('testController', testController);

    testController.$inject = ['$filter', '$window' ,'$rootScope' ];

    function testController($filter, $window , $rootScope) {
        //Some Logic's Here
        function print() {
            $window.print();
        }
    }
}());
</script>
</apex:component>
```

The code for TestTemplate

```
<apex:component >
<script type="text/ng-template" id="vlcCompareModal.html">
    <a clasS="btn btn-default" ng-controller="testController as smallGroup"  ng-click="smallGroup.print()">Print</a>
</script>  
</apex:component>
```

I'm getting error saying Argument 'testController' is not a
Link : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=testController&p1=not%20a

Comment: Updated. I believe still the error exists. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Aman what do you mean by that using that only will give you faster results?

Comment: Yes @Aman, still the error exists.

Comment: where have you read that? I have never heard such thing

Comment: @DeepakBandi I think you need to define your controller after $injecting dependencies. Like `testController.$inject = ['$filter', '$window' ,'$rootScope' ];` and then `app.controller('testController', testController)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your controller after the controller function:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

     testController.$inject = ['$filter', '$window' ,'$rootScope'];

     function testController($filter, $window , $rootScope) {
         //Some Logic's Here
         function print() {
            $window.print();
         }
     }

     angular.module('vsTestApp')
         .controller('testController', testController);
}());
```

Comment: since he's defining the controller as named function (and not using var testController = function(){..}) this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is off topic but that is a mess.

Why would you simply not do:

```
.controller('testcontroller', ['$filter', $window', '$rootscope', function($filter, $windwo, $rootscope) {

}]);
```

Much more concise and easier to read and understand for others looking at your code.

Comment: Its a code which is already written and I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: looks like somebody munged the typescript way of doing things and the vanilla way.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `<c:testController />` instead of `<c:TestController />` ?

Comment: It is the way filename is saved and the file name is TestController.